# Algorithm to find solution to $ax^2 + by^2 = 1$ in a finite field

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field, and let $a,b \in \mathbb{F}$ be given, subject to $a\ne 0, b \ne 0$.  Consider the equation

$$ax^2 + by^2 = 1.$$

It is guaranteed that [there exists a solution to this equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/572975/14578).  My question:

> Is there an efficient algorithm to compute a solution to this equation, given $a,b$?

The proof I've seen that there exists a solution doesn't immediately yield an efficient algorithm (it'd require enumerating all of the elements of $\mathbb{F}$, which is inefficient).  Is there a more efficient algorithm?

By efficient, I'm thinking of something with polynomial running time, i.e., where the number of basic field operations is polynomial in $\lg |\mathbb{F}|$.

This reminds me a little bit of Pell's equation, in a finite field, but I haven't seen how to translate those methods over to a finite field.  I don't know if that is a distraction or if it's somehow relevant.

Comment: The case ${\text{char}}\left({\mathbb F}\right) = 2$ is particularly simply, as $r\to r^2$ is injective then. So if $a\neq 0$, for any choice of $y$ (fix it first as you please) you will have exactly one $x$ solving the equation. You can find it by considering that $$x = x^{2^n} = (x^2)^{2^{n-1}}= (a^{-1}(1-by^2))^{2^{n-1}}$$ when $|{\mathbb{F}}| = 2^n$ (any element satisfies $g^{2^n}=g$ in such a ${\mathbb{F}}$), and then repeated-squaring to get that power. This is polynomial in $n$.

Answer (score 5):

There is a natural (randomized) algorithm:

1. Choose $x,y$ uniformly at random from $\mathbb{F}$.
2. Let $s = ax^2 + by^2$.  If $s \ne 0$ and $s$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}$, let $r= \sqrt{s}$ (the square-root can be computed efficiently in a finite-field) and set $x'=x/r$, $y'=y/r$.  Now $x',y'$ are a solution to the original equation, as can be readily verified, so we are done.
3. If not, go back to step 1.

---

Is there any guarantee that this algorithm's expected running time will be polynomial?  Heuristically, we would expect the answer to be yes: about half of the elements of $\mathbb{F}$ are squares, so (assuming that $ax^2 + by^2$ is distributed uniformly at random when $x,y$ are) the number of iterations of this algorithm will be geometrically distributed with parameter $1/2$, or 2 iterations in expectation.  Of course, this is just a heuristic.

Can we justify the running time more rigorously?  I argue below that the answer is yes.

---

Let's dispose of a trivial situation first: if we are in characteristic two, then every value has a square root, so the above algorithm will succeed with near-certainty.  (Letting $s=ax^2 + by^2$, we have $\Pr[s=0]=1/|\mathbb{F}|$, and assuming $s\ne 0$, $s$ is surely a square, so step 2 succeeds with probability $1-1/|\mathbb{F}| \ge 1/2$.)

Therefore, in what remains, we can assume that we are in odd characteristic.

---

To help us reason about this situation, let's divide both sides by $a$, to get the related equation

$$x^2 + c y^2 = d,$$

where I've defined $c=b/a$, $d=1/a$.  Any solution to this equation will solve the original equation.

I will argue that $x^2 + c y^2$ is approximately uniform on $\mathbb{F}$, when $(x,y)$ is uniform on $\mathbb{F}^2$.  By appropriate scaling, this will show that our heuristic was indeed rigorous.

I'll define a multiplicative group $\mathbb{G} = (\{(x,y) : x^2 + c y^2 \ne 0\}, \otimes)$, where the group operation $\otimes$ is defined as follows:

$$(x_1,y_1) \otimes (x_2,y_2) = (x_1 x_2 - c y_1 y_2, x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1).$$

It is straightforward but tedious to verify that this indeed forms a group operation.  Also, there is a group homomorphism $N : \mathbb{G} \to \mathbb{F}^*$ given by

$$N(x,y) = x^2 + c y^2.$$

Again, it is straightforward but tedious to verify that this is a homomorphism of multiplicative groups, e.g., $N((x,y) \otimes (x',y')) = N(x,y) \times N(x',y')$.

Now let $s,t$ be two non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}$.  Define

$$S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{G} : N(x,y) = s\},
T = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{G} : N(x,y) = t\}.$$

Since $N$ is surjective (as [shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/572975/14578)), these are two cosets of the kernel of $N(\cdot)$, and any two such cosets must have the same size (Lagrange's theorem), so it follows that $|S|=|T|$.  But $s,t$ were arbitrary non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}$, so it follows that $N(x,y)$ is distributed uniformly on $\mathbb{F}^*$ when $x,y$ is distributed uniformly on $\mathbb{G}$.

Now $\mathbb{G}$ holds the set of $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+cy^2\ne 0$, so we must consider the set $A=\{(x,y) : x^2+cy^2=0\} = \mathbb{F}^2 \setminus \mathbb{G}$.  It turns out that this set is not very large: if $-c$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}$, then $|A| = 2|\mathbb{F}|-1$, otherwise $|A|=1$.  It follows that, when $x,y$ are chosen uniformly at random from $\mathbb{F}$, the probability that $ax^2 + by^2=0$ is small ($\le 2/|\mathbb{F}|$), so the probability that we succeed in step 2 of the algorithm at the top of this answer is at least $(1-2/|\mathbb{F}|)/2$.  Thus, the expected number of iterations is constant and small.  This rigorously justifies the heuristic analysis above, and shows that the algorithm runs in polynomial time, as required.

---

Where on earth did this mysterious group $\mathbb{G}$ come from?  The intuition is that it comes from looking at the a complexification of $\mathbb{F}$.  In particular, let $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{F}(\sqrt{-c})$, i.e., adjoin a square root of $-c$.  Define a norm on $\mathbb{K}$, so that $N(z) = z \times \overline{z}$ where $\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$: or more precisely, define $N(\cdot)$ by

$$N(x+y\sqrt{-c}) = (x+y\sqrt{-c}) (x-y\sqrt{-c}) = x^2 + c y^2.$$

This norm is multiplicative: $N(z_1 z_2) = N(z_1) N(z_2)$ for $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{K}$, and $N(z) \in \mathbb{F}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{K}$.  The group operation of $\mathbb{G}$ is just multiplication in $\mathbb{K}$, and the group homomorphism $\mathbb{N}$ is just this norm.  This intuition only works out if $-1$ is a non-square in $\mathbb{F}$ (so that $-c$ will be a non-square), but I think the argument I gave above actually holds regardless of whether $-1$ is a square or not.

---

I hope I haven't made any mistakes.  My thanks to Steven Stadnicki for his careful proof-reading of an earlier attempt at answering this question and to Pablo Rotondo for helpful comments that improved this answer.

Comment: *Feedback:* Nice, looks correct, you should add that $N$ was surjective (as you proved in your previous thread) to justify that the preimages are cosets of $\ker(N)$.

Comment: One thing though: About the average iterations of your algorithm, you would also have to consider the size of the set $A=\{(x,y) : x^2 + c y^2 = 0\}$ (its size is no more than $2|{\mathbb F}|$), because that check $s\neq 0$ in step $2$ actually influences the average running time too. You have shown that, provided that you have not hit $A$, then $N(x,y)$ is uniformly distributed over ${\mathbb F}^*$

Comment: Excellent points, @PabloRotondo!  Thank you.  I've revised my answer based upon your comments.  I appreciate the helpful suggestions and the review.