# Show that if p is prime and $p \nshortmid abc$ then the congruence $ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has a solution other than $(0,0,0)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

> Show that if p is prime and $p \nshortmid abc$ then the congruence $ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has a solution other than $(0,0,0)$

I don't see any clear path to tackle the problem. I've been trying with quadratic residues but I haven't noticed anything worthy. I've also done a lot of examples but I haven't found any method to find solutions

Comment: Related/same proof technique: [Show that for any prime $ p $, there are integers $ x $ and $ y $ such that $ p\mid x^{2} + y^{2} + 1$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260928)

Comment: Yes, there is actually always a solution with $z=1$.

Comment: I am sure the technique in the thread Barto linked has been used way earlier. But, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/573562/11619) is the oldest hit I could find. Weak search-fu :-(

Comment: Related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1816

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I guess you mean on this site; but it is a step in the method Hardy and Littlewood use to show the sum of four squares is positive universal

Comment: LOL! Thanks @Will !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $p\nmid abc$, we have $$ \left|\,A =\left\{ax^2:x\in\mathbb{Z}_p\right\}\,\right| =\frac{p+1}2 $$ and $$ \left|\,B =\left\{-c-by^2:y\in\mathbb{Z}_p\right\}\,\right| =\frac{p+1}2 $$ Since $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$, and $|A\cup B|\le\left|\mathbb{Z}_p\right|=p$, we must have $$ |A\cap B|\ge1 $$ Therefore, as Thomas Andrews comments, there is a solution with $z=1$.

Comment: Did you mean $B = {by^2+c}$? Also, couldn't the intersection between both of them end up implying that x and y equal zero?

Comment: $B = \{by^2+c\}$

Comment: @CamiloEscobar: no, I meant $B =\left\{-c-by^2:y\in\mathbb{Z}_p\right\}$. That way, any element of $A\cap B$ says that  $ax^2\equiv-c-by^2\pmod{p}$.

Comment: @CamiloEscobar: as for $x=y=0$, since $z=1$, we won't have $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.