# The solvability in field of Prime Characteristic p

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be a field of prime characteristic $p>0$.The question is what we can say about the solvability of the equation $x^2+y^2=-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for every prime $p$. I have found out that there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ different squares in the field $\mathbb{F}_p$. I was thinking about the circle of radius $kp-1$ has integer point for some $k$.

Comment: A duplicate. Did you search the site?

Comment: Oops. Not a good target. Looking for an older and a simpler version.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/572975/11619) may be better.

Comment: Thank you, I am new here and I don't know how to use the site in the best way of it.